# DevExpress XtraBars Grouping BarButtonItem

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress

I am using DevExpress **BarManager** and added three **BarButtonItem**. Now I want to make group of these BarButtonItems.

For example, clicking on the button shows popup menu or something like dialog which shows BarButtonItems with Glyphs.

How to achieve it?

[This link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5406) works for Ribbon Control but we are instructed to not use RibbonControl or RibbonManager.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add a new [BarSubItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarSubItemtopic) which represents sub-menu and then move your items into this sub-menu:
[image]

Related help-article: [The List of Bar Items and Links](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2511)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. However, Instead of Showing text "Menu", can we show the image or Glyph item?

Comment: How I can add Controls(BarButtonItem) in PopupControlContainer ?

Comment: Regarding images - yes, you can - please use the [PaintStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarItemPaintStyleEnumtopic) property.

Comment: Regarding PopupControlContainer - it is not quite clear to me how it related to the original question...

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Infact I need only images, no text. I have managed to do it using your suggestion `BarSubItem`. I have removed all the captions and used Glyphs and it fulfilled my requirement. Thanks.